# Из чисел и знаков сделать правильные неравенства

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Даны n целых чисел и ряд из n коробок. Между коробками фиксировано расположены знаки неравенств. Разработайте программу, которая "помещает" числа в коробки так, чтобы неравенства были правильные.

Например, числа: 2 5 1 0. Знаки: < > <. Решение: 0<5>1<2.

Есть наработки, но всё плохо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    getline(cin, s1);
    getline(cin, s2);
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());

    int cur1 = 0, cur2 = 0, cur = 0;
    int kolright = 0, countright = 0;

    vector<int>rez(s1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s2[i] == '<')
        {
            rez[cur] = s1[cur1];
            cur1++;
            cur2++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            while (s2[i] == '>')
            {
                kolright++;
                i++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= kolright; j++)
                rez[cur2 + j] = s1[cur1 + kolright - j];
            cur2 += kolright; cur2++;
            cur1 += countright; cur1++;
            kolright = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < rez.size(); k++)
        cout << rez[k] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не парься, для зачёта хватит и полного перебора.

Comment: @Akina А если коробок - штук 100?... :)

Comment: @Harry Ну будет долго работать, и что? Ну получит зачёт в следующем году, когда программа отработает, делов-то...

Comment: Напишите что именно не так с этим кодом.

Comment: @Akina Вы оцениваете полный перебор 100! годом?... 8-/

Comment: Если это вопрос по спортивному программированию то обязательно указывайте ссылку на задачу. Это позволит избежать лишних вопросов.

Comment: Не хотите подумать о применении топологической сортировки?

Comment: Тут можно применить bogosort =)

Comment: @Harry, Из-за того, что верных решений много, будет немного меньше, чем n!. (0<5>1<2, 1<5>0<2, 0<2>1<5, 1<2>0<5) Насколько меньше, оценивать не берусь.

Comment: @vp_arth С тем же успехом можно уповать на то, что первый же вариант подойдет. В наихудшем случае - потребуются все n!

Comment: А наихудшим случаем, вероятно является полностью отсортированная последовательность? aka `<<<<<`

Comment: Если серьёзно, я бы начал с заполнения минимально подходящей последовательности. `0<1<2>1<2<3>2>1>0>-1`. Тогда заполнение коробок будет проще, т.к. понятны ранги. Максимум входных чисел попадает в коробку с макс. рангом и т.д.

Comment: А кстати, числа все разные или могут быть одинаковые?...

Comment: Про это ничего не сказано.

Answer (score 1):

Даём каждой коробке уровень. Начинаем с самой левой. Её уровень 0 (можно n - 1, для удобства) . Если < уровень следующей коробки + 1 от текущей, если > уровень -1. Это делается за линию. Потом выдаём номера. Начинаем с самого большого уровня и выбираем самые большие из оставшихся. Если во время шага 1 завести массив уровней (всего может быть 2n-1 уровней), в котором хранить какие коробки на этом уровне, то тоже работает за линию.

Comment: Единственное, в случае возможности одинаковых входных чисел — нужно определиться с критерием невозможности решения. Простейший пример: `1 > 1 `. Ну и нет, не за линию. Формулировки вроде "самые большие из оставшихся" подразумевают сортировку.

Comment: Да, ещё нужна сортировка n*log(n). Я думал числа по порядку идут. И если числа могут быть одинаковыми, это решение не работает.